# Error syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... en una Function personalizada en php

Tags: php, funciones

Poseo una funcion que cuenta los registros que cumplen con tres condiciones.

```
function ContarPubliNL($iDUsu) {//Cuenta las Publicaciones no leidas
include("Conexion.php");
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL. FUNCTION TagSoft" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
$BQuery1 ="SELECT Aux1 FROM Usuario WHERE IdEmpresa =".$iDUsu;
$sql1 = mysqli_query($con,$BQuery1);
if (!sql1) { echo 'error en el Buscar aux';}
$fila1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1);
$uPvisto = 0;
if (!empty($fila1['Aux1'])){
    $uPvisto = $fila1['Aux1'];
}
echo $uPvisto;   
$BQuery ="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM Publicaciones where IdPuesto < '".$uPvisto."' && Publicado = 1 && IdEmpresa =".$iDUsu ;
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$BQuery);
if (!sql) { echo 'error en el conteo';}
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
return $fila['total'];
?>
```

El tema es que la pagina me da este error:

```
Error syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...131
```

Ahi en 131 es el cierre de la funcion " ?> "
 No se que esta mal....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único malo que veo es que no tienes la llave para cerrar la función antes del ?>

Comment: Mira que la revise 100 veces, no puedo creer. Mil gracias